# ssh over USB on Mac osx returning port 22 network is unreachable

Tags: macos, networking, ssh, usb

When I try to SSH over USB to my device running linux, I get "ssh: connect to host 10.90.1.2 port 22: Network is unreachable"

Mind you, I can run the same command "ssh root@10.90.1.2" on my linux machine and another mac, but on my boss's brand new machine OSX, no dice.

If I type "ifconfig" on the working mac, I get an entry like

```
en2: flags=...
  ether 5a:...
  inet 10.90.1.1
```

On the non working machine, running if config shows a similar block except the part where I have "inet 10.90.1.1..." is missing.

On both machines I have gone to Network and set my RNDIS/Etho Gadget to configure IPv4 manually and have an IP address of 10.90.1.1.

Can anybody point me to a setting that might cause the ifconfig outputs to be different? I'm just not proficient with Macs.

Thanks.

Comment: Full output of `ifconfig -a` on working and non-working machines would be useful. The output of `system_profiler SPNetworkDataType` would also likely be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to use 10.90.1.1 on multiple computers at the same time? If so, that'll cause trouble (& should get you an error message). You need a unique IP number for each computer on the network.